# Remove a specific Tag with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm currently trying to write a script using python with `Beautiful Soup` to change the camera in indigo file (.igs), but I'm encountering a certain problem :

```
<scenedata>
   <tonemapping> <camera>...</camera> </tonemapping>
   <camera>...</camera>
</scenedata>
```

I would like to only remove the "camera" tag that **is not inside "tonemapping"** tag.

I tried `soup.find('').replace`_with and `soup.select('camera')` but it always removes all camera tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just check parent name and remove what you don't need.

```py
import bs4

text = """
<scenedata>
   <tonemapping> <camera>...</camera> </tonemapping>
   <camera>...</camera>
</scenedata>
"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, features="lxml")

for cam in soup.select("camera"):
    if cam.parent.name != "tonemapping":
        cam.extract()
```

Answer (score 1):

Select `<camera>` that **is not** child of `<tonemapping>` simply per `css selector`.

**Option#1** - If there is only one tag:

```
soup.select_one(':not(tonemapping) > camera').extract()
```

**Option#2** - If there are multiple tags:

```
for cam in soup.select(':not(tonemapping) > camera'):
    cam.extract()
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data="""
<scenedata>
   <tonemapping> <camera>...</camera> </tonemapping>
   <camera>...</camera>
</scenedata>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

for cam in soup.select(':not(tonemapping) > camera'):
    cam.extract()
```

#### Output

```
<scenedata>
<tonemapping> <camera>...</camera> </tonemapping>

</scenedata>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt it to your case, but try something along the lines of:

```
    # build soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, features='html.parser')
    
    # select first  tag
    map_tag = soup.select_one('tonemapping')
    
    # select the first  tag inside the selected  tag
    camera_tag = map_tag.select_one('camera')
    
    # remove the selected  tag
    camera_tag.decompose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc="""
<scenedata>
   <tonemapping> <camera>...</camera> </tonemapping>
   <camera>...</camera>
</scenedata>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

s = soup.select_one('scenedata tonemapping + camera')
t = s.decompose()


print(soup)
```

## Output

```
<scenedata>
<tonemapping> <camera>...</camera> </tonemapping>

</scenedata>
```